# FindSoup.cmake error while compiling with brew

Tags: cmake, makefile, homebrew, libsoup

I was following instructions to compile dino.im on macOS (fresh installation) and I encountered two errors. I was able to fix one but cannot find any solutions to solve the other one.

This is what the terminal prints:

```
CMake Error at cmake/MultiFind.cmake:20 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSoup.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Soup", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Soup" with any of
  the following names:

    SoupConfig.cmake
    soup-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Soup" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Soup_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Soup"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  plugins/http-files/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_packages)
```

1. I installed all the required dependencies as per the wiki by running:
   `$ brew install adwaita-icon-theme glib glib-networking gpgme icu4c libgpg-error libgcrypt gtk+3 gtk4 libsignal-protocol-c libgee libsoup libsoup@2 sqlite cmake gettext ninja vala qrencode libxml2 gspell gst-plugins-base srtp libnice`
2. I encountered that gst-plugins-base can no longer be directly installed on a Mac via brew so I fixed that by installing streamer (all gst- plugins come bundled)
3. After installing the dependencies, I cloned this repository : `https://github.com/dino/dino.git`
4. I went through these steps:

```
$ brew sh
$ ./configure (this is where I encountered errors)
$ make
$ exit
```

Then I got this error:

```
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Adwaita (missing: Adwaita_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindAdwaita.cmake:9 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/MultiFind.cmake:20 (find_package)
  main/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_packages)
```

which I was able to fix by simply installing libadwaita

4. After doing the above, I re ran ./configure but now I got error which is the primary concern of this question, the findsoup.CMake. I couldn't find any relevant solutions hence I am asking here.

Comment: is this some formula? can you run `brew gist-logs formula` to dump out the logs?